# Вывод товаров списком или сеткой

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть вывод товаров сеткой (т.е. каждый товар имеет ширину col-md-4). Необходимо сделать так чтобы пользователь сам мог выбрать в каком виде выводить, списком или сеткой (col-md-4 или col-md-12). Сейчас сделал так, при нажатии на кнопку(например: выводить списком) с помощью js удаляю класс col-md-4 и добавляю класс col-md-12. Естественно все работает но только если не перезагружать страницу. Как сделать так чтобы и при перезагрузки страницы настройки не сбивались? Где хранить настройки?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете при переключении вида отправлять ajax на сервер, в котором будете сообщать, что переключился вид. На сервере записывать в Cookie текущий вид, а при перезагрузке страницы проверять Cookie и рисовать именно тот вид, на который в последний раз переключался пользователь.

Comment: Тоже об этом думал. Но в opencart есть такая функция, и вроде там такие настройки не хранятся в сессиях или в куках

Comment: Если пользователь имеет аккаунт, можно для этого пользователя хранить значение, в котором он просматривает список, в базе данных. Ищи идентифицировать через куки, но хранить значение в базе. В любом случает надо знать, что это именно тот пользователь, который переключал вид